# Accessing the root directory to access a background-image?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a background image on my webpage but when I add in my code it doesn't show the image. The page is linked to the home page but how would I get my background image to appear when the user selects the help guide tab, which it then takes them to another page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        h1 { text-align: center; font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive; font-size: 50; }
        p.p-stage { text-align: center; font-family: Arial; font-size: 150%; }
        p.p-help { text-align: center; font-family: Arial; font-size: 100%; }
        body { 
            background-image: url("assets/images/Festival.jpg");
            background-height: 100%;
            backgroud-width: 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        #rcorners2 {
            margin: auto;
            text-align:left;
            border-radius: 25px;
            border: 2px solid #000000;
            padding: 20px; 
            width: 1000px;
            height: 750px;  
            overflow: auto;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Help Guide</h1>
<p class ="p-stage" id="rcorners2">Stages:<br><br>1. How to add a stage?<br><br>
To create a stage please do this.................<br><br>

2. How to delete a stage?<br><br>
To delet a stage please do this.................<br><br>
3. Add a help guide with a questions users may come up with and then com up with answers. 

</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM3Jd.png)

Comment: have you checked the browser dev tools ? is the image resource being loaded ?

Comment: Look in the network tab for the image. Does it show up? Does it load or fail to load?

Comment: yeah it says failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (not found) @Utkanos

Comment: not being loaded up @Pierre

Comment: So the URL you're using to access it is wrong. The URL is relatove to the CSS file, not the page it's loaded on. So you need to figure out the relative URL to the image from the CSS file that calls it.

Comment: update your css with valid path, and you'll be done

Comment: but the saved image is in that path, I have also called that image the same way in my home page and it seems to work. so I am not sure how to fix it? @Pierre

Comment: clear cache ? checked caps letters ? no htaccess redirects or deny clauses ?

Comment: could it be because I am calling this page from my home page?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. it is due to path of the root directory. To go back in the root directory where the image file might be in use:

```
background: url("../../assets/images/Wallpaper4.jpg");
```

the 2 dots go back one folder so two .. means you have gone back 2 folders

Comment: The point is images loaded from CSS are loaded *relative to the location of the CSS file making the request*. So it's that relationship - CSS file path to image file path - you need to know.